# gatsby-plugin-layout still mounting layout on each page load

Tags: gatsby

I have installed `gatsby-plugin-layout` into my project files, created `src/layouts/index.js`, and added `gatsby-plugin-layout` to `gatsby-config.js`. The Gatsby app compiles and can be served on the development server, but via `console.log` outputs in `componentDidMount()` of my Layout component, I see that the layout component still is re-mounted on each page load. My goal is to have the Layout component only mount a single time during the course of the React app.

**src/layouts/index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "../components/header"
import Footer from "../components/footer"
import Particles from "react-particles-js"
import particlesConfig from "../json/particlesjs-config-particles.json"

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Layout mounted");
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Layout updated");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>      
        <Header />
        <div id="particlesContainer">
            <Particles params={particlesConfig}/>
        </div> 
        {this.props.children}
        <Footer />      
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Layout
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    /*...*/
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-csv`,
      options: {
        delimiter: ['|'],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        /* ... */
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized my issue. I didn't remove the Layout component from each individual page, thus not reaping the benefits of `gatsby-plugin-layout`. Upon removing the inclusion of the Layout component in each of my pages, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Gatsby sites are NOT single page application that you get when you use React without any other frameworks. Gatsby is a static site generator that uses React internally but builds real HTML pages.

Therefore each page that implements the layout will define the layout as part of its page HTML DOM. Thus it will be remounted for each page because it is defined in each single HTML page and componentDidMount() is called each time you navigate to a page.

Regarding one of the plugin features you use `Persisting layout between page changes for e.g. animating navigation`: I would guess there is come kind of global state defined in the plugin components that handles this feature. This is the case in my project that I use without the plugin.

Comment: The way the plugin's description is worded, the gatsby docs really make it seem like you can mount components in your referenced layout file only once. Comments on Reddit show that other people have been able to use this plugin to achieve this functionality.